# What hairspray brands are known to contain PVA / PolyVinylpyrrolidone

Tags: adhesion

It's common to use hairspray, especially AquaNet, as a bed adhesive. My understanding is this works because the spray includes a chemical called polyvinylpyrrolidone, or PVA.

What other brands of hairspray are known to contain this chemical in sufficient concentrations to work as an effective adhesive in 3D printing applications?

Comment: PVA is in sprays and white glues (school glue and wood glue), polyvinylpyrrolidone is found in some glue sticks. See e.g. [this answer](/a/11183/).

Comment: This is too broad as an unlimited list question.

Comment: Just read the ingredients list..?

Answer (score 2):

From an MSDS for AquaNet hairspray:

> Water (Aqua), Dimethyl Ether, SD Alcohol 40-B (Alcohol Denat.),
>   **VA/Crotonates/Vinyl Neodecanoate Copolymer**, Acrylates Copolymer,
>   Aminomethyl Propanol, Sodium Benzoate, Cyclohexylamine, Triethyl
>   Citrate, Cyclopentasiloxane, Sodium PCA, Masking Fragrance (Parfum)

The MSDS doesn't mention polyvinylpyrrolidone.

I suspect that the "PVA" here is the VA/Crotonates/Vinyl Neodecanoate Copolymer.  A little googling indicates that this is a common ingredient of hair sprays, and works by forming a thin coating over hair to prevent it from adsorbing moisture.

I stumbled upon three types of Loreal(R) hairspray that have these ingredients.  It seems likely that there are more.

Disclosure:  I use AquaNet on an aluminum bed as a PLA bonding agent, and on my Prusa PEI covered bed as a PET-G release agent.